# mysql remotely connection issue

Tags: mysql, database, localhost, remote-access

I installed MySQL on a linux system. I have running Debian. I can access mysql with local ip address through command on local system as well as remotly

```
./mysql -h 192.168.1.151 -u root -pabcd
```

. Now I added a host(192.168.1.152), and I can not use AddedHost to connect remotely from other machine, i have given all privileges to this host as

```
grant all on *.* to 'root'@'192.168.1.152' identified by 'abcd';
```

but i failed to connect locally as well as remotly.
i got the error when i execute command

```
./mysql -h 192.168.1.152 -u root -pabcd
```

error 2003 (hy000) can't connect to mysql server on '192.168.1.152' (111)

please help me out to sort out this issue.
Thanks
Rahul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means, [from here(FAQ)-](http://www.webyog.com/faq/content/23/15/en/error-no-2003-can_t-connect.html)

> - There is no MySQL server running at the specified host
> - Connection to the MySQL server is not allowed using TCP-IP. Check the 'skip-networking' setting in the MySQL configuration file (my.ini
>     on Windows, my.cnf on Unix/Linux). It shall be commented out like
>     '#skip-networking'. If it is not commented out, then do it and restart
>     the MySQL server for the change to take effect. SQLyog needs to
>     connect using TCP-IP.
> - Some networking issue prevents connection. It could be a network malconfiguration or a firewall issue. We have experienced sometimes
>     that some firewalls (ZoneAlarm in particular) is blocking TCP-IP
>     connections even if it claims to be disabled. Most often it will help
>     to uninstall and reinstall the firewall.
> - When trying to connect to a MySQL server at an ISP this error message often indicates that direct connection to MySQL has been
>     blocked. You must then use HTTP-tunneling or SSH-tunneling to connect.

Comment: thanks to reply ashwin. There is no fire wall issue on my system and i have comment out '#skip-networking' and '#bind-address' in my.cnf file.and i have fired command after run mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have granted priveleges for your user at your IP.  Localhost is usually the only granted login with permissions.